# Breadth first search with three-letter words, optimization

Tags: python, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm using a breadth-first search algorithm in Python to find the shortest "path" from a three-letter word to another. I've got it working but the performance is horrible and I suspect my word children generation function.

Basically for every word I pop from the queue I generate all other three-letter words that can be formed by exchanging one letter. The function works like this:

```
#Pseudo code
For each position (1-3)
    For each letter (a-z)
        create a new word by exchanging the letter at the position
        if this word is a valid word and is not used earlier
             add it to the return list

return the list
```

This usually takes about 0.03 seconds.
Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What is a path between two words?

Comment: Clarification: a path is a series of words where each word is generated by exchanging a single letter in the previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do want to reinvent the wheel, perhaps this would help (N.B. This has set literals so needs at least Python 2.7):

```
from collections import defaultdict

WORDS = {'cat', 'hat', 'sat', 'car', 'cad', 'had', 'pad', 'pat', 'can', 'man'}

D1 = defaultdict(set)
D2 = defaultdict(set)
D3 = defaultdict(set)

for w in WORDS:
    D1[w[:2]].add(w)
    D2[w[0]+w[2]].add(w)
    D3[w[1:]].add(w)

def follows(w):
    followers = set(D1.get(w[:2]).union(D2.get(w[0]+w[2]), D3.get(w[1:])))
    followers.discard(w)
    return followers

for w in WORDS:
    print(w, follows(w))
```

Comment: This is a really great solution. My runtime changed from 80 sec to 0.5 sec.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have a list of valid words and you are actually not looking for a single path (why would you care to optimize for that) but for lots of paths. This can be done quite easily with [networkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov):

```
from networkx import Graph
from networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths import shortest_path, all_pairs_shortest_path

from itertools import combinations

WORDS = {'cat', 'hat', 'sat', 'car', 'cad', 'had', 'pad', 'pat', 'can', 'man'}

def makeGraph(words):
    """ create a graph where nodes are words and two words are 
        connected iff they have one different letter """

    G = Graph()

    # all word combinations
    for a,b in combinations(WORDS,2):
        # number of different letters
        diff = sum(1 for x,y in zip(a,b) if x!=y)
        if diff == 1:
            G.add_edge(a,b)
    return G

g = makeGraph(WORDS)
# path between two words
print shortest_path(g, 'cat', 'pad')

# generating all shortest paths is way more efficient if you want many paths
paths = all_pairs_shortest_path(g)
print paths['cat']['pad']
```

Thanks to @Ducan for the example words.

If you really want to implement these algorithms yourself you can find plenty descriptions at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem). The classic single source shortest path algorithm is [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm) and the classic all pairs shortest path algorithm is [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm).

Comment: Not bad.  I thought at first that `makeGraph` might have an infeasible complexity with a full valid word list, but the list I found had 668 words, which is only 222,778 iterations.  Definitely worth it, especially if you do `makeGraph` once and compute a lot of different paths afterward.

Comment: This is a very good answer to the question naturally following the one I asked. The whole thing is actually a part of a school assignment*  so I'm kinda doing this one step at a time and trying to figure out most details myself.
*:we are encouraged to seek information online, so this isn't cheating =D)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel in a perhaps suboptimal way: use existing modules:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/altgraph/0.8

Comment: how will a library designed for graph transversal speed his algorithm up? i'd be the first to eat my own words, but this seems like it would have equivalent performance if not add overhead.